# Unable to scrape parts of a page webpage with scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I'm using scrapy to crawl an e-commerce website I'm experienced with simpler websites where scrapy alone or with splash/selenium handle most cases.
I have a new situation where I have no experience to deal with. From my investigations it could be like a captcha but without any request to the user.

I've made tests to solve it with scrapy alone, scrapy and selenium with no success.

With my scrapy request I receive the following response

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <title>Challenge Validation</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_sec/cp_challenge/sec-2-9.css">
      <script type="text/javascript">function cp_clge_done(){location.reload(true);}</script>  
      <script src="/_sec/cp_challenge/sec-cpt-int-2-9.js" async defer></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">sessionStorage.setItem('data-duration', 5);</script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="sec-container">
        <div id="sec-text-container"><iframe id="sec-text-if" class="custmsg" src="https://beta.elcorteingles.es/sgfm/statics/eci_non_food/contents/cc/cca.html"></iframe></div>
        <div id="sec-if-container">
          <iframe id="sec-cpt-if" class="crypto" data-key="" data-duration=5 src="/_sec/cp_challenge/ak-challenge-2-9.htm"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

With the chrome inspector i see also noticed two GET requests (non-java) that might be related:

```
check -> returns HTML ( ... <title>RP iframe</title> ...)
check-session?origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.elcorteingles.es -> returns HTML (...<title>OP iframe</title>...)
```

Using scrapy shell with view(response) it looks like a captcha situation, waiting for something. Page example could be:

scrapy shell "https://www.elcorteingles.es/supermercado/0110120903000022-coosur-aceite-de-oliva-intenso-1-botella-1-l/"

The title 'challenge validation' suggests it. I have no idea how to handle with this case. From research, I've seen solutions involving scrapy middleware but for cases where input was asked from the user. I found no example similar to this case. Any guidance on how to proceed is appreciated.

Comment: The website is using javascript heavily. There are some hidden APIs that give access to some data. There are two options, either browser activity or trying to recreate API requests if possible. What are your data needs ?

Comment: Thanks for your help. With chrome inspector I've disabled javascript, disabled cache, reload the page and I still see the full data. I though this would indicate that no javascript is used, but I agree that API calls are being just don't know how to reproduce them. My data needs (from the page 'https://www.elcorteingles.es/supermercado/0110120903000022-coosur-aceite-de-oliva-intenso-1-botella-1-l/', looking into the browser) are the content of the field 'Ingredientes y alérgenos' and the content of the field 'Nutrientes'. Thanks for your interest

Comment: Having looked at this, within the first requests there's the HTML document and a javascript file. I've not looked directly into the JS file with too much depth, but my guess is that most of the page source is dynamically requested. This is why in scrapy shell, you only get javascript related HTML. You'll need use splash or selenium with this I think to get the information you require. If you're not familar with splash, or selenium_request, importing the selenium package is do-able. You could even make a spider middleware to render the page using selenium package.

Comment: I have experience of using both splash and selenium with scrapy. I've tried scrapy with both, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: Hey @CTavar. Did you find the solution for this? I have the same issue.

Comment: looks like a what you want is to modify scrapy-selenium and then use the wait to wait for a few seconds. the javascript blocks some requests for a number of seconds before getting the data. that is the "challenge verification"

Answer (score 0):

You can use [playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro) to easily parse the page. You can use playwright [locators](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/locators) to select page elements or if you prefer to use Scrapy's [selectors](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html) you can always do so. Scrapy also allows the integration of playwright through [scrapy-playwright](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-playwright).

```py
from playwright.sync_api import Playwright, sync_playwright
from scrapy import Selector


def run(playwright: Playwright) -> None:
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=True)
    context = browser.new_context()
    page = context.new_page()
    page.goto("https://www.elcorteingles.es/supermercado/0110120903000022-coosur-aceite-de-oliva-intenso-1-botella-1-l/")
    
    # Wait page to load
    page.wait_for_timeout(20000)
    response = Selector(text=page.content())
    
    # page.get_by_role("link", name="Aceptar").click() # Cookie box accept

    # ---------------------
    context.close()
    browser.close()


with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    run(playwright)
```